# Bootstrap forms in a website that no Boostrap is implemented

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that's created using normal HTML and CSS without using Bootstrap but I like the Bootstrap form styling.

My Question is how can I implement bootstrap's form style in my website and making sure it will not interfere with my website's style?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through bootstrap docs? http://getbootstrap.com/css/ Get started here

Comment: yes sure I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

And you must first include the Bootstrap css and then your css. It will not interfere with each other.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/your-css.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then say you want to use the `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12` classes of bootstrap with your own CSS, you can do something like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 your-class">
    Some Stuff
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="your-class">
        Some Stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Where your css for `your-class` can be

```
.your-class{
    max-width:220px;
    margin-top:45px;
}
```

I hope this helps. You should go through the Bootstrap Docs and probably this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/).